# Remove Ubuntu 13.04 from triple booted computer

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, uninstall, dual-boot

I have a triple-booted desktop computer with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04. I plan to permanently keep Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 but I want to switch Ubuntu 13.04 to another operating system as Unity on 13.04 seems to slow my computer down and usually freezes it.

Since I can't post images in these questions, [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAuoJ.png) of GParted with my set up right now:

I want to remove Ubuntu 13.04 from my triple boot but am not sure if removing it right now will mess up 12.04. I know windows 7 is sda1 to sda 3, Ubuntu 12.04 is sda 5 and Ubuntu 13.04 is sda 7. Should I just delete it? Are there any problems I should worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that you will have any problem. What you need to is *format* the Ubnutu 13.04 partition, this would remove all the files present on it.

You can perform this from the Gparted in your 12.04 most probably, but your partition should be unmounted.

**But before formatting it**, please run the following commands from the terminal in your **Ubuntu 12.04**

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

This will ensure that the grub is installed according to your 12.04, and wont get corrupted on deleting 13.04

Then you can safely format it.
After formatting it, run (type in the terminal)

```
sudo update-grub
```

from your Ubuntu 12.04 .This would update the Grub Configuration file and now it would show only the entries for your 12.04 and windows 7.

Now you can use the formatted partition for storing data.

Thank You.

If you have any queries please let me know.

Comment: After doing the above, please let us know if you were successfull ! and if my answer helped you, please mark it as solved :)